# ReactJS - Unbound Breackpoint

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, breakpoints, vscode-debugger

I'm working on a project with ReactJS and I have a problem when I try to launch the debugging console.
When I set breakpoints, I get 'unbound Breakpoint' as message. I don't know how to solve this problem knowing that I searched everywhere before posting this message, if someone could help me, it would be cool,
Thanks in advance,

```js
 {"version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "pwa-chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
            "url": "http://localhost:8080/",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
 }
```

Comment: These are the common reasons for that: 
1) you're not running your debugger in the same port as your react web app.
2) you didn't instantiate your local server using `npm run start` before lunching the debugger